# Is there a way to launch a systemd `.service` file when in emergency mode?

Tags: linux, systemd

Is there a way to launch a systemd `.service` file when in emergency mode?

I have a small systemd `.service` file made to run a program when in emergency mode. When I enter into emergency mode, (either with executing `sudo systemctl emergency` or adding `systemd.unit=emergency.target` when in the GRUB editor, like [this](https://www.tecmint.com/boot-ubuntu-in-rescue-mode/#ubuntuemergency)) it will not execute and the status shows that it has never been executed.
The `.service` file is enabled.

When executing manually with `systemctl start` in emergency mode, it works as expected.

Here is the file:

```
[Unit]
After=emergency.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/user/.local/bin/exec.sh &> /dev/null &

[Install]
WantedBy=emergency.target
```

I'd like to add that I have added the `&> /dev/null` to remove any output from the program, and the `&` in the end because for some reason it resolved some other problem I had.

I am on Arch Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you not use any shell features in the `ExecStart` command line. They will almost certainly not work. Instead, read up on Systemd services and select the correct `Type` etc. `oneshot` is probably not the correct choice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you be able to share how I should improve this file? I am sure you are right, but I'm new with systemd, so I don't know how to script this well.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the emergency service with

```
systemctl edit emergency.service
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer explains how to start an editing session, but what exactly needs to be modified, removed or added?